# Python - no such file or directory after updating to Monterey

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-monterey

I recently updated my macOS to Monterey and I am not able to use the Python from terminal.

`which python`

`/usr/local/bin/python`

`python -V`

`Python 3.7.8`

When i run python command in terminal using zsh or bash, i get the error:

`zsh:  bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python: no such file or directory`

I tried updating path in zhrc and bash_profile, but i am still getting the same error
Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You either have an alias or a symbolic link somewhere.  Check `~/.bashrc` and your `~/bin`.  Do `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` -- is it a symbolic link?

Comment: yes @TimRoberts - /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.7

Comment: @TimRoberts - i removed the symlink. However, the error i see is that it looks for  /usr/bin/python whereas the python is inside /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that alias -- you will want to put it back.  The problem is that something is pointing TO /usr/bin/python, and that's what you need to fix.  You might try `hash -r` to remove the list of remembered paths.